# Ansible создание пользователя с паролем

Tags: ansible, yaml

Всем добрый день, начинаю изучать Ansible так что прошу не судить сильно за качество плейбука
Вопрос заключается в том что что при указании на прямую в строке то пользователь создается с паролем и могу войти по ssh. Но если я передаю пароль через переменную то все, я не могу войти по ssh будто пароль не устанавливается. Прбовал двумя путями(в коде показано) но не один не срабатывает как кроме передавать прямо.
Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему? опирался на документацию там указано

```
If provided, set the user’s password to the provided encrypted hash (Linux) or plain text password (macOS).
```

Вот часть плейбука

```
  vars:
    username: ayu21
    password_user : 123qwe!@#
  

  tasks:
  - name: Get name if debian family when create user
    ansible.builtin.user: 
      user: "{{ username }}"
      password : "{{ '123qwe!@#' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      # password: '{{ password_user }}'
      home: /home/"{{ username }}"
      shell: /bin/bash
      groups: sudo
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
      ssh_key_file: .ssh/"{{ username }}"
    when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, получилось решить самому, неправильно передавал переменную.

Правильно передавать будет так:

```
 password : "{{  password_user | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```